# How to rotate an Azure storage account access key from C# code?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, access-keys, key-rotation

I have an Azure storage account. It has a number of access keys associated. From the Azure web GUI it is possible to "rotate" these keys.

[image: Key rotation in the GUI]

It is also possible to rotate them from the command line, using (I believe) `az storage account keys renew`.

I would like to rotate these keys from C# code. I have trouble finding the right object that lets me do this.

I know of NuGet packages like **Azure.Storage.Blobs** and **Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table**. Is there any class in any NuGet package of one of those families that has a feature that lets me rotate/renew/regenerate these storage account access keys?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nuget package you would want to use is [`Azure.ResourceManager.Storage`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.Storage). Once you create/get an instance of [`StorageAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.storage.storageaccount?view=azure-dotnet-preview), you would need to call [`RegenerateKeyAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.storage.storageaccount.regeneratekeyasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview#Azure_ResourceManager_Storage_StorageAccount_RegenerateKeyAsync_Azure_ResourceManager_Storage_Models_StorageAccountRegenerateKeyParameters_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) method to regenrate a key.

Here's the sample code for the same. Please note that you will also need to install [`Azure.Identity`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity/) Nuget package.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Storage;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Storage.Models;

namespace SO69882633
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string subscriptionId = "23456789-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        private const string resourceGroupName = "resource-group-name";
        private const string storageAccountName = "storageaccountname";
        private const string keyToRegenerate = "key2";//Key to regenerate. Could be either "key1" or "key2"
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var credentials = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
            string storageAccountResourceId =
                $"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storageAccountName}";
            StorageAccount storageAccount = armClient.GetStorageAccount(storageAccountResourceId);
            var keys = await storageAccount.GetKeysAsync();
            foreach (var key in keys.Value.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{key.KeyName}: {key.Value}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("===========================");
            StorageAccountRegenerateKeyParameters parameters = new StorageAccountRegenerateKeyParameters(keyToRegenerate);
            var result = await storageAccount.RegenerateKeyAsync(parameters);
            Console.WriteLine($"\"{keyToRegenerate}\" key regenerated successfully.");
            Console.WriteLine("Listing keys again (just to make sure ;-))...");
            keys = await storageAccount.GetKeysAsync();
            foreach (var key in keys.Value.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{key.KeyName}: {key.Value}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("===========================");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm hesitant to use that package because apparently there is no official release of it, only beta releases. Moreover, I could not figure out how to instantiate a `StorageAccount`. Could you show - or link to an example of - how to instantiate a `StorageAccount`? And, crucially, _what version of the NuGet are you using_?

Comment: Understood your comment about the SDK being in preview. There's an older version of the SDK available as well: [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage/). I believe the current version of this new SDK is `1.0.0-beta.3`. HTH.

Comment: The newest pre-release is 1.0.0-beta.3, yes. But the sample you linked to is not from 1.0.0-beta.3. The sample appears to be from an unreleased master, and the code base seems to have changed _a lot_ since the last pre-release. When I check out tag 1.0.2 from their GitHub I cannot find any `StorageAccount` class.

Comment: I took the sample code from their tests. Are you open to use this pre-release version? I will try to write some code to make use of this version of the SDK.

Comment: I am open to using it for these purposes, yes.

Comment: Updated my answer with working code. HTH.